# Review of sprint board during the sprint session?

Tags: scrum, sprint, product-owner, sprint-backlog

What is the name of the session that the scrum master and PO during the sprint review the sprint board to see and the progress, update the status of the tickets and sometimes include some team members for this?
In some cases I have heard it as grooming meeting, but usually grooming is the refinement before sprint planning.

Comment: "The sprint board" isn't something that Scrum requires.  Therefore, Scrum cannot have an event that needs it.  The Team can choose whatever means they find helpful to coordinate work and make progress visible.  Communication with PO and SM is also up to the team to determine, though I would expect the latter to regularly attend the Daily Stand-Up.

Answer (score 4):

Such an event does not exist in Scrum. In Scrum, the Sprint Backlog is "a plan by and for the Developers". The Developers are expected to choose a mechanism (which may or may not be a board) to give stakeholders a "visible, real-time picture of the work" that is being done over the course of the Sprint to accomplish the Sprint Goal. The Developers should be the one updating their Sprint Backlog to give the Product Owner visibility into the status of their work.

Answer (score 2):

This touches on the roles & responsibilities of the scrum team:

- [Product Owner](https://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#product-owner) is responsible for the management of the Product backlog
- [Developers](https://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#developers) are responsible for creating the Sprint plan (Sprint Backlog) as well as adapting their plan each day toward the Sprint Goal;

If you are looking for a status updates mid-sprint, it sounds like there may be a transparency and inspection breakdown (two of the cornerstones of [Scrum theory](https://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#scrum-theory)). Questions to bring back to the team:

- Is the current project tracking tool (e.g. Board) a good fit for the team? Are the developers able to easily keep it up to date?  Does the Product Owner have access? Is the information being documented of value?
- If the tool is a good fit for the team, what barriers are stopping the developers from updating? For example, is the daily scrum (or other meetings) being perceived as status update and therefore no need for update in the Sprint board implying a reliance upon the Scrum Master as participate for Product Owner update?

If you get to the root cause of why your transparency issues exist, then your inspection issue may no longer be a problem.

In terms of the other ceremonies mentioned, depending who you talk to sprint planning, sprint grooming, and sprint refinement may be perceived as exchangeable concepts or distinct. "Sprint planning" is the term referenced in Scrum.

**[Sprint planning](https://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#sprint-planning):** Often composed of at least three parts: Why does this work matter? What work is available? How will it be accomplished? Takes place at the beginning of the sprint.

**[Sprint Review](https://www.scrum.org/resources/what-is-a-sprint-review):** Take place at the end of sprints and is an opportunity for the team to inspect outcome of the sprint, gather actionable feedback, and discuss the future. Participation is often inclusive including Developer team, Scrum Master, Product Owner, stakeholders.

Common agenda items:

- Overview of what was “Done” and what has not been “Done”;
- What went well, problems, mitigations;
- Demonstration of work that is “Done” and answers questions;
- Product Owner overviews current product backlog, and projects targets/delivery dates